# How to export contact list that includes total contributions to date?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, contributions, export

I can only **either** export my contacts, or contributions. Is there a way to export an amalgamated list of contacts including all contributions made by each contact, either that year/per year/within date rage, or total to date?

I tried to use the advanced search, to find contacts within a certain group + with contributions of certain $ amount. When I try to export that list, there is no available field to export "contributions". Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

If you add the Summary Fields extension then you can choose to have a field for 'total amount', total this financial year, count this financial year, etc etc, which then makes exporting much easier as it is 'just' another custom field

- https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/joinerys-more-summary-fields
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/synopsis

Answer (score 0):

When you run the advanced search, change the option at the very top called "Display results as" from contact to contributions. That should allow you to export contribution information for the search results. (There should also be basic contact information available when exporting contribution information.)

[image]